# Count video watch time when close the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

In my project I have to store in database, How many second or minute I have watched. In my model pop-up I am displaying the video. The below code count the second when I PAUSE THE VIDEO, BUT I am **interested to count the second** when I click on the **CROSS button of my model** pop-up.

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");

var timeStarted = -1;
var timePlayed = 0;
var duration = 0;
// If video metadata is laoded get duration
if(video.readyState > 0)
  getDuration.call(video);
//If metadata not loaded, use event to get it
else
{
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', getDuration);
}
// remember time user started the video
function videoStartedPlaying() {
  timeStarted = new Date().getTime()/1000;
}
function videoStoppedPlaying(event) {
  // Start time less then zero means stop event was fired vidout start event
  if(timeStarted>0) {
    var playedFor = new Date().getTime()/1000 - timeStarted;
    timeStarted = -1;
    // add the new number of seconds played
    timePlayed+=playedFor;
  }
  document.getElementById("played").innerHTML = Math.round(timePlayed)+"";
  // Count as complete only if end of video was reached
  if(timePlayed>=duration && event.type=="ended") {
    document.getElementById("status").className="complete";
  }
}

function getDuration() {
  duration = video.duration;
  document.getElementById("duration").appendChild(new Text(Math.round(duration)+""));
  console.log("Duration: ", duration);
}

video.addEventListener("play", videoStartedPlaying);
video.addEventListener("playing", videoStartedPlaying);

video.addEventListener("ended", videoStoppedPlaying);
video.addEventListener("pause", videoStoppedPlaying);
```

```
<div id="videoModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" onclick="PlayVideoCount();" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<video id="vid" autoplay="" controls="" width="100%" height="100%"></video>
</div>
<div>
```

I want to count the second when `PlayVideoCount();` function called.

Comment: I am not quite clear with the question, you want to record the amount of time video is played when your video is closed. Why don't you use the same videoStoppedPlaying on your cross button?

Comment: @poo Can you also suggest me how I can convert `SECOND INTO Minute.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your HTML code is but I made a small code maybe you will get the point. If not then comment down, and I will help you out. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qoh9tsvw/)

> HTML

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>

<button onclick="playVid()">Play</button>
<button onclick="pauseVid()">Pause</button>
```

> JavaScript

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', (event) => {
  console.log('Total Time ', event.srcElement.duration);
});

video.onpause = (event) => {
  console.log('Paused at ', event.srcElement.currentTime);
};

function playVid() {
    video.play();
}

function pauseVid() {
    video.pause();
}
```